# How would one create a genie?

Tags: character-creation, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm trying to create a character based around the Genie from Aladdin. Able to grant wishes with nearly infinite versatility, but not able to act on it's own free will; totally subject to the will of it's 'master' which is whomever controls the lamp.

How is this possible to do, in Mutants and Masterminds? And more specifically, is it able to be done while still remaining balanced?

Notably, this is a PC, not an NPC; GM story powers do not apply here.

Comment: What do you mean by balanced in this sense?

Comment: Balanced as in... Not blatantly overpowered. It's level of power still needs to be within the scope of a PC. I guess realistically, that's probably a bad question for here, though.

Comment: What is the character's Power Level?

Comment: The PL will be anywhere from 8 to 10, with 120-150 PP. I realize that's probably a bit low, for the concept, but... I'd still like to try. Let's assume PL 8 though? @MikeQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Your "Genie" can't be any more powerful than a regular PC

Just to get it out of the way, you'd be building your genie to the same PL limit as anyone else, so your "wishes" need to built just like any power.

### But that really doesn't limit them that much

*Variable* lets you manifest a large number of powers. With *Affects Others*, you can even give powers to other people (up to what your GM consider appropriate). *Transform* gives you a lot of options for turning one thing into another. And you just give them whatever other powers make sense from *Blast* to zap things on command to *Flight* to get around to *Morph* to do your best Robin Williams impressions. As for the idea of only being able to do what is commanded, that's more or less a Complication for when it would be convenient to be able to do more, but practically speaking, most of the time such characters just get to do what they will, the same way that you can generally dictate the actions of your minion.

### The question is, what do you want do with the character?

I'm not certain whether you're genuinely wanting to always be ordered around, or if it's more flavor. Having a kid sidekick who's the one commanding you still gives you agency, but adds the Complication that you need to keep track of them, and that sometimes the GM may dictate their actions. Or were you looking to gain some sort of additional benefit from only being able to do what is ordered, a point break or an end-run around PL?

Much like utility characters in the game, this might be the sort of concept that shows up in the comics, but which doesn't really work all that well to play.

Comment: Thank you kindly! Negative, I'm not aiming to cheat the game; I just wasn't certain how to build it properly. And, yes: I suppose I am trying to make a sort of servant character. Powerful in theory, but subjected to the will of it's master. But able to think freely, and possibly even twist the wishes recieved (akin to the 'most powerful being' wish being used against Jaffar). I feel like it would make for interesting roleplay. Worth a try anyhow, eh?